# ATL OLEDB Consumer with Azure

Tags: c++, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, azure

I am trying to use the `ATL OLEDB` Consumer within VS 2010 (tried also VS2012) to generate the Accessor class using the Wizard.
I am connecting to my `Azure MSSQL DB` using DBO rights.
I always get the error

```
Could not get the DBSCHEMA_COLUMNS schema. (The provider might not support it).
```

Connecting and running the Wizard with my locally installed `SQL Server 2008 R2 express` works perfectly fine.
Any idea? Any recommended workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Azure DB does not (fully) support  OLEDB:

> Connecting to Microsoft Azure SQL Database by using OLE DB or ADO is not supported.

(Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee336245.aspx#dlaps)

I will reconsider resigning my application to use ODBC.